# Java read the file name and stored in ascending order

Tags: java, java.nio.file

Reading the files from a particular directory and stored all the file names in the arraylist

```
File directory = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = directory.listFiles();
        int fileCount = directory.list().length;
        List<String> files = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fileCount; i++) {
            String inputFilePath = path + listOfFiles[i].getName();
            String inputFileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();
            files.add(inputFileName);
        }
```

my expectation to stored the files in ordered (ascending order) but the actual is

```
1.jpg
10.jpg
11.jpg
12.jpg
13.jpg
14.jpg
15.jpg
16.jpg
17.jpg
18.jpg
19.jpg
2.jpg
20.jpg
21.jpg
22.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
7.jpg
8.jpg
9.jpg
```

let me know how to store the file in ascending order  like `1,2,3,4,5....10,11....20,21...etc.,)`

Comment: Files are already in ascending order... What else do you expect? If you are absolutely sure all the file names (removed extension) could be parsed as a number, then do it, but it does sound tricky a lot...

Comment: You have to sort the list. I think there is no order of files in the file system

Comment: An option would be to create a custom comparator that's is going to be like the String::compare one just will take in hand the length first then the current character itself.

Comment: You have sorted the files lexicographically not by integer.  You can split the file extension and add a comparator to compare the integer part.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **[Collections.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))** along with a custom comparator which compares the integer prefix of each filename, like below on your ArrayList `files`:

```
Collections.sort(files, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        int s1Num = Integer.valueOf(s1.split("[.jpg]")[0]);
        int s2Num = Integer.valueOf(s2.split("[.jpg]")[0]);
        if (s1Num == s2Num) { return 0; } 
        else if (s1Num <  s2Num) { return -1; }
        else { return 1; }
    }
});

for (String file: files) {
    System.out.println(file);
}
```

**Output:**

```
1.jpg
2.jpg
3.jpg
4.jpg
5.jpg
6.jpg
7.jpg
8.jpg
9.jpg
10.jpg
11.jpg
12.jpg
13.jpg
14.jpg
15.jpg
16.jpg
17.jpg
18.jpg
19.jpg
20.jpg
21.jpg
22.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to sort your files objects by their names in ascending order. You need to create you file name comparator. Pseudo-code here.

```
class FileNameComparator implements Comparator<File> {

    private final Pattern NUMERIC_PART_PATTER = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)[.]");

    @Override
    public int compare(File file1, File file2) {
        String name1 = file1.getName();
        String name2 = file2.getName();
        int part1 = retrieveNumericPart(name1);
        int part2 = retrieveNumericPart(name2);
        return part1 - part2;
    }

    private int retrieveNumericPart(String str) {
        Matcher matcher = NUMERIC_PART_PATTER.matcher(str);
        if (!matcher.find()) {
            return 0;
        }

        String group = matcher.group(1);
        return Integer.parseInt(group);
    }
}
```

Then just use this comparator.

```
File[] sortedFiles = Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, new FileNameComparator());
```

Then you can loop through you files, and they are sorted as you wanted! Without a comparator, you will get a list of Strings sorted alphabetically (as Strings are sorted by default.)

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's in that order. The files are not ordered arithmetically but lexicographically. You would have to rename all single digit files to include a leading zero to achieve the order you're expecting or write a custom ordering method and apply it to a list that contains your filenames.